# Redmine project menu bar dissapeared when adding new plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am beginner in the development for Redmine. I created a plugin and added it into project menu. But when i clicked to this tab, it does not link to page I want and the project menu bar disappears. It's hard to control all activities on project management. What should i do?

This is code in my `init.rb` file:

```
permission :project_plan, { :project_plan => [:index,:show] }, :public => true
menu :project_menu, :redmine_project_plan, { :controller => 'project_plan', :action => 'index' }, :caption => :project_plan_title
```

Comment: can you tell , how you added the plugin ?

Comment: At what point you are stuck & what have you tried so far? Can you post some code?

Comment: I created and added plugin into: '$\BitNami Redmine Stack\apps\redmine\htdocs\plugins' following instruction in: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugin_Tutorial,
My code have added in my question

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you don't give the project_id as a param, the code above should look more like

```
permission :project_plan, { :project_plan => [:index,:show] }, :public => true
menu :project_menu, :redmine_project_plan, { :controller => 'project_plan', :action ='index' }, :caption => :project_plan_title, :param => project_id
```

And on the controller you need recue this information :

```
@project= params[:project_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with my Redmine plugin, after hours of digging and research found out what appears to be the issue. What is important is to update the @project variable with project id parameter passed into your show method. Here is my controller file:

```
class YearlyController < ApplicationController
      unloadable
      helper :issues
      include IssuesHelper

      def show
           require_login       
           @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])       
      end
end
```

And init.rb file:

```
Redmine::Plugin.register :weekly do
  name 'Weekly Plan plugin'
  description 'Display weekly plan for current and previous week'
  version '0.0.2'
  menu :project_menu, :yearly, { :controller => 'yearly', :action => 'show' }, :caption => 'Roadmap Year', :after => :overview, :param => :project_id
  menu :project_menu, :weekly, { :controller => 'weekly', :action => 'show' }, :caption => 'Weekly Plan', :after => :yearly, :param => :project_id
  settings :default => { :weeklabel_name => 'Weekly Label' }, :partial => 'settings/settings'
  project_module :weekly do
    permission :view_weekly, :weekly => :show
    permission :view_yearly, :yearly => :show
  end
end
```